# Existing SASS/Compass files that are migrated to Rails 3.1

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I have just updated my application from rails 3.0.7 to 3.1.0.rc4.

In my old app., my .sass files are in the ~/app/stylesheets directory.

Should I move these files to the ~/app/assets/stylesheets directory?

Answer (score 0):

If you want them to be automatically processed by the asset pipeline, then yes.  You can manually configure sass to read them from anywhere, but that is the easiest way.

Note: make sure you have sass-rails in your Gemfile.  You might want to have a glance at the asset pipeline [documentation.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)